# Firestore - OrderBy won't work if placed inside return code

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I want to order my data by "Time", but whenever i try to add .orderby("time"), it displays an error.

My Get function"

```
return this.firestore.collection('East_Area').snapshotChanges();
```

I tried doing this:

```
return this.firestore.collection('East_Area').orderBy("time").limit(3).snapshotChanges();
```

Am i doing something wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Would be better to have the error message. You probably need to create a composite index in order to make sorting requests, see : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview

Comment: Hello! There is no error message on the console, but VS Code highlights the code as RED (error, i presume)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
return this.firestore.collection('East_Area').orderBy("time").limit(3).snapshotChanges();
```

into this:

```
do this then: return this.firestore.collection('East_Area', ref => ref.orderBy("time")).snapshotChanges()
```

`snapshotChanges()` is a method inside `angulareFire` but you are using plain javascript, therefore you need to use `get()` method to retrieve data.

Comment: Thanks for answering! But i get this:

'orderBy' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreCollection<{}>'.

Comment: what is the type of `this.firestore`?

Comment: Here's the code for that: 

 private firestore: AngularFirestore

Comment: do this then: `return this.firestore.collection('East_Area', ref => ref.orderBy("time")).snapshotChanges()`